# Defining a WHERE clause from a subquery for a query to create a handy view

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, query, linestring

It is about my implementation from an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/33084/15459) of this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33055/15459).
It is more an postgresql issue than a GIS issue, whereas it is about geometries and spatial queries.

I want to create a view from the query below, whereby I can select the result by an ID (that defines a linestring).
My problem is, that I had no success with coding the query in that way, that for every linestring only one `newpoint` is created that is half the length away from the linestring (see last subquery 'newdistance').
I tried to `SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)...` but that failed.

The linestring table:

```
id smallint NOT NULL,
geom geometry(linestring, 31468)
```

I have the same problem in another query, to "extract" a WHERE clause (here in the first part of the query) from an subquery.

My goal is to have a view `newpoint` (from the query below) whereby I can query like this

```
SELECT * FROM newpoint WHERE id=1
```

The query:

```
WITH line AS
    (SELECT
        geom
    FROM linestring
        WHERE id=1),
points AS
    (SELECT
        ST_StartPoint(geom) AS A,
        ST_EndPoint(geom) AS B
    FROM line),
azimuth AS
    (SELECT
        ST_Azimuth(A,B) AS azimuth
    FROM points),
distance AS
    (SELECT
        ST_Distance(A,B) AS length
    FROM points),
newdistance AS
    (SELECT
        length + (length * 1/2) AS newlength
    FROM distance)

SELECT
    ST_SetSRID(ST_Translate(A, sin(azimuth) * newlength, cos(azimuth) * newlength), 31468) AS newpoint
FROM newdistance, azimuth, points
```

Setting the WHERE clause id=1 at the end of the query didn't succeed.

**EDIT**

When I use

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (geom) ...
```

in the last part of the query it works ONLY with 2 objects (linestrings). With more than 2 linestrings it doesn't work.

Here is a picture, how does it has to look like.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip the trig,

```
create view mypoints as
select id, 
  st_makepoint(
    st_x(st_endpoint(geom)) + (st_x(st_endpoint(geom))-st_x(st_startpoint(geom)))/2, 
    st_y(st_endpoint(geom)) + (st_y(st_endpoint(geom))-st_y(st_startpoint(geom)))/2
  ) as geom 
from mytable;
```

then

```
select geom from mypoints where id = 1;
```

should work fine, for all values of id

Comment: So my approach is good for learning how to use subqueries =)! I like your approach, thank you. But can you adapt my code in that way I can use it like a view? I have nearly the same structure in another query.

Comment: Not really. That layout forces an execution order on the system which doesn't allow the system to easily add a clause. I'd end up adapting your code to run in one query, so the system can easily plan it out. Think less procedurally and more in sets.

Comment: A little bit late, but I think I can wrap the query into a function. There I can play with parameters.