# How to extend a straight line in postgis?

Tags: postgis, query, linestring, extend

I have a postgis table of simple linestrings, each one is a straight line with just two points. I want to select every linestring, but extended from both sides by 1 meter. So i have lines, that are longer by 2 meters. How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I seems very similar to post "[postgis, extrapolate a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33055/postgis-extrapolate-a-line)". If I avoid repetition of cited post, I think you just need to extrapolate beyond your extreme points. In a query you get something like this should work:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_TRANSLATE(a, sin(az1) * len, cos(az1) * 
len),ST_TRANSLATE(b,sin(az2) * len, cos(az2) * len))

  FROM (
    SELECT a, b, ST_Azimuth(a,b) AS az1, ST_Azimuth(b, a) AS az2, ST_Distance(a,b) + 1 AS len
      FROM (
        SELECT ST_StartPoint(the_geom) AS a, ST_EndPoint(the_geom) AS b
          FROM ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(1,2), ST_MakePoint(3,4)) AS the_geom
    ) AS sub
) AS sub2
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful: this method swaps points `a` and `b` in the end.

Use

```sql
SELECT ST_MakeLine(ST_TRANSLATE(a, sin(az2) * len, cos(az2) * 
len),ST_TRANSLATE(b,sin(az1) * len, cos(az1) * len))

  FROM (
    SELECT a, b, ST_Azimuth(a,b) AS az1, ST_Azimuth(b, a) AS az2, 1 AS len
      FROM (
        SELECT ST_StartPoint(the_geom) AS a, ST_EndPoint(the_geom) AS b
          FROM ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(1,2), ST_MakePoint(3,4)) AS the_geom
    ) AS sub
) AS sub2
```

to have `a` and `b` not swapped.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  The original answer did have the endpoints swapped, but the fix is to interchange the `ST_Translate` expressions.

Comment: Interchange the `ST_Translate` expressions works as well.
In my proposed version I removed the `ST_Distance` from the `len` and switched `az1` and `az2`, that's why it works, or have I missed something?

Comment: Agreed, your version is equivalent, and simpler in some ways.