# How to merge geometries in postgis if they intersect?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Basically I want to merge all the line segments that intersect into one line as shown below in orange

So each line segment would have their own id

Edit: seems this is too hard to solve with SQL, one of my colleagues came up with an answer using Python

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16698/join-intersecting-lines-with-postgis

Comment: Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: @GobTron I tried the solution on that question but it didn't work, I guess it's because mine is different since there are no different types of roads

Comment: I believe this could help as well https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257196/merge-features-n-time

Comment: Since I gave the answer @BFlat linked, check out [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257595/clean-the-merge-from-some-features?noredirect=1&lq=1) one, too, it´s basically an update to the linked answer with better performance and robustness.